# How to pass data viewcontroller via Tab bar Controller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

I want to pass datum from view controller to view controller via tab bar controller.

I mean, my storyboard is like this.

```
View Controller → Tab Bar Controller → VC1/VC2/VC3
```

For the purpose of this, I tried to use `PrepareforSegue`, but it's failed.
The code is here.

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
friendsDetailViewController* vc = [[friendsDetailViewController alloc] init];
vc = (friendsDetailViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
 
vc.candidateid = [[NSString alloc] init];
vc.candidateid = [candidateid objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
```

Though I was trying to pass data from VC to VC1, `SIGABT` happened on the last line.

---

#### Update:

I've got figured out how. Here is the script:

```
friendsDetailViewController* vc = [[friendsDetailViewController alloc] init];
UITabBarController* tbc = [segue destinationViewController];
vc = (friendsDetailViewController*)[[tbc customizableViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Firstly, I have to attach Tab Bar Controller.
Secondly, retrieve each View Controller's pointer.
You can select by using objectIndex.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer then you can accept it and get some points for it.

Comment: instead of `customizableViewControllers`, you should use `viewControllers`. `customizableViewControllers` only return view controllers that are re-arrangable. Should one view controller become unarrangable, you might get some unintended behavior.

Comment: when I put `UITabBarController* tbc = [segue destinationViewController];` in, it says it doesn't like 'segue'.

Answer (score 0):

In childviewcontrollers of tab bar controllers you can easily pass data by using

```
[self.parentViewController.view setAccessibilityValue:@"your data"];
```

and can easily access this data in other child viewcontrollers of tabbar

or you can add an object in nsuserdefaults for some key and attach that key in parentviewcontroller.view ..
get that object by using objectforkey from nsuserdefaults in next viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I had NSString which i waned to be sent like this:

`View Controller → Tab Bar Controller → VC1/VC2/VC3`

Before anything else I created **ViewController-s** and **TabBarController** classes and connected them with **storyboard**.

This worked for me:

First lets send data from **ViewController** to **TabBarController**:

1. add segue to connect **ViewController** and **TabBarController** in storyboard and name it:
   **toMyTabController**
2. add property u want to change in **TabBarController**:

   `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;`
3. add this method somewhere in ViewController.m:

`-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
         {
          if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toMyTabController"])
           {
           MyTabController  *tabController = (MyTabController *)segue.destinationViewController;
           tabController.name = @"SOME AWESOME NAME";
           }
         }`

==================================================================================
Now lets send data from TabBarController to ViewController

1. Add property to every ViewController where you want to send info, and lets name it name (so creative)
   add this to **ViewController1.h, ViewController2.h, ViewController3.h

   `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;`
2. add this to **ViewController1.m**, **ViewController2.m**, **ViewController3.m**

   `@synthesize name;`
3. go to your **TabBarController.m** and add this in **ViewDidLoad** method:

`for (UIViewController* myController in self.viewControllers)
    {
       if([myController respondsToSelector:@selector(setName:)])
        {
           [myController performSelector:@selector(setName:) withObject:self.name];
        }
    }`

Thats all,
Hope it helps. Good Luck